# How to include a custom attribute in the product details page?

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, theme

So I've looked around for this information, and the vast majority of information I can find, is how to add a custom tab with custom attribute information, which is NOT what I want.

What I'm looking to do, is add a custom attribute that contains different text per product, just below the "in stock" message in my theme. 
I'm fairly certain I need to edit:

```
app > design > frontend > theme > subtheme > Magento_Catalog > templates > product > view > product_info_main.phtml
```

The attributes codename is: "stockmessage", how do I include the value of that attribute in each products detailed view page ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add below code inside

> app/design/frontend/Package/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.tab" template="product/view/product_info_main.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
        <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Your Tab Title</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Call your attribute inside your phtml file

```
echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getStockmessage(), 'stockmessage');
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm NOT looking to do. I'm trying to insert without adding any tabs. I want to the text value to be inserted.